# Android SupplicantState returns COMPLETED after disconnecting from network

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

The problem:
When I connect to wifi, and then disconnect, the following code gives me SupplicantState.COMPLETED

```
SupplicantState supState;
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
supState = wifiInfo.getSupplicantState();
```

Comment: Same problem but only in <=API19. It works okey in API19>